# Need help understanding ordinal logistic regression output, R

Tags: r, ordered-logit

I THINK this will boil down to a simple yes/no answer, but allow me to walk you through my thought process.

I have data like this:

```
    df<-structure(list(Survey = structure(c(1L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 
5L, 1L, 2L, NA, 1L, 4L, 4L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 5L, 1L, 4L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 4L, 3L, 4L), .Label = c("Never", "Rarely", "Sometimes", 
"Often", "Always"), class = "factor"), Score = c(2.27272727272727, 
18.1818181818182, 29.5454545454545, 22.7272727272727, 43.1818181818182, 
25, 75, 61.3636363636364, 29.5454545454545, 6.81818181818182, 
54.5454545454545, 36.3636363636364, 36.3636363636364, 70.4545454545455, 
22.7272727272727, 45.4545454545455, 31.8181818181818, 61.3636363636364, 
15.9090909090909, 47.5, 11.3636363636364, 52.5, 22.7272727272727, 
22.7272727272727, 4.54545454545455, 37.5, 35, 65.9090909090909
)), row.names = c(NA, -28L), groups = structure(list(.rows = structure(list(
    1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 12L, 13L, 14L, 
    15L, 16L, 17L, 18L, 19L, 20L, 21L, 22L, 23L, 24L, 25L, 26L, 
    27L, 28L), ptype = integer(0), class = c("vctrs_list_of", 
"vctrs_vctr", "list"))), row.names = c(NA, -28L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame")), class = c("rowwise_df", "tbl_df", "tbl", 
"data.frame"))
```

Consisting of a survey question that we gave participants with answers on a likert-type scale of never, rarely, sometimes, often, and always.  Those participants also had a "score" from a previous instrument (continuous variable).   What we're trying to examine is whether the continuous "score" predicted the survey response.

Given my survey results are ordinal, and given my score variable is continuous, I figured that an [ordinal logistic regression like shown in these examples was my best bet](https://stats.idre.ucla.edu/r/dae/ordinal-logistic-regression/).

So I ran this code:

```
library(MASS)
m <- polr(Survey ~ Score, data = df, Hess=TRUE)
summary(m)
(ctable <- coef(summary(m)))
p <- pnorm(abs(ctable[, "t value"]), lower.tail = FALSE) * 2
(ctable <- cbind(ctable, "p value" = p))
confint.default(m)
```

Like in that UCLA example and I received this output:

[image]
[image]
[image]

When sharing this output with my colleagues, I want to make sure I am interpreting correctly (and it was the right test).

So two part question:

-Given I am trying to see whether "score" predicted "Survey" response, was this the correct statistical test to choose?
-If it was the correct test, I interpret the results as "yes, there is a significant relationship (basing that on the confint not crossing zero) and for a one unit increase in 'score' the odds of answering higher on the survey multiply by 1.065.  Is that correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are correct.  Assuming that the proportional odds assumption is not  strongly violated, the statistical test and parameter estimates are valid.  Just strike the word *significant* which has very little meaning, and report there is good evidence (P=0.0058) against the supposition of no effect of score.  Then state the confidence interval and don't tie it to a test.  You can further clarify "odds of answering higher" as odds that $Y \geq j$ for all $j$ other than the reference category.  Most importantly check the parameterization in `polr` to make sure the direction is as you stated: increasing `score` implies increasing response.  Some implementations of the proportional odds model have it the other way when $\beta > 0$.

If you want to get more output specifically for the proportional odds model see the `lrm` function in the R `rms` package.  Along with the `Mean` function you can get predicted mean scores for any covariate settings, and with the `ExProb` function you can get predicted exceedance probabilities.  `lrm` is set up so that $\beta > 0$ if the relationship is positive.

Comment: Above and beyond, thank you!